# Multi smol boi puzzle I: apologies

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, grid-deduction, crosswords

<sub>***Disclaimer: Jryy, svefg bs nyy, V jbhyq yvxr gb ncbybtvmr. Abg sbe npgvbaf (jryy bxnl, sbe npgvbaf), ohg sbe zl fzby obv pvcure. Vg frrzf gung zl svefg fzby obv chmmyr jnf whfg n ovg gbb uneq. Fb, gb znxr vg hc gb rirelbar, V thrff fnqyl unir gb znxr lrg nabgure fzbv obv chmmyr gb tvir rirelbar gur xrl gb gur Ivtrarer pvcure va gur svefg bar.  Ubjrire, guvf bar jba'g or rnfl. Vg jvyy or fzby, ohg vg jba'g or rnfl. Yrg zr gryy lbh gung. Guvf vf tbvat gb or sha. >:3***</sub>

---

Goals:

> Solve both puzzles
>
> Achieve the final code $\color{white}{\text{and name the gimmick used in Puzzle 1}}$

---

***puzzles*** :3

---

[Puzzle 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLkSH.png)

[image]

> Hint: This part of the puzzle has a ***gimmick*** to it. I'll be keeping the gimmicks relatively simple for now, however will try to make them more complex as I start making more and more puzzles. Note that Puzzle 2 ***will not*** have a gimmick to it due to the fact that it would simply be too difficult to implement a gimmick into a puzzle that doesn't even need them.

> 1. $\color{black}{\text{Former infamous Geometry Dash hacker (2020-2023) nickname}}\color{white}{\small\text{hint:outside the atmosphere+England,__}}$
> 2. $\color{black}{\text{"No" in Japanese, in romanji}}$
> 3. $\color{black}{\text{Finding _ _ _ _ (not what you think it is)}}$
> 4. $\color{black}{\text{Emoticon used back at least as far as April 11, 2000.}}\color{white}{\small\text{not a hint, but it probably originated in chat rooms.}}$
> 5. $\color{black}{\text{That hurts >:(}}\color{white}{\small\text{you really can't get this?}}$
> 6. $\color{black}{\text{Served by Culvers (spelled backwards)}}\color{white}{\small\text{hint: 11 15 13 85 93 91, and don't you dare think it's a Polybius square.}}$
> 7. $\color{black}{\text{My literal favorite food (maybe the green letters can help?)}}\color{white}{\small\text{at least it rhymes with no.10}}$
> 8. $\color{black}{\text{_ _/him}}$
> 9. $\color{black}{\text{Another word for pig}}$
> 10. $\color{black}{\text{Not alive, a female deer}}\color{white}{\small\text{hint: across, then down}}$
> 11. $\color{black}{\text{A long time _ _ _.}}$
> 12. $\color{black}{\text{Which came first: the chicken or the _ _ _?}}$

[Puzzle 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLvDo.png)

[image]

Hint for puzzle 2: A fixed version of the Nonogram (more readable) [(play online)](http://www.landofcrispy.com/nonogrammer/nonogram.html?mode=play&puzzle=5%7C8%7C1x1.1x2,1x3.1x1,1x1.1x6,1x1.1x2.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x2.1x3%7C1x5,1x1,1x4,1x3,1x1,1x3,1x3.1x1,1x1.1x3%7Cx,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x&palette=white.grey.X,black..)

> [image]

If you have solved both puzzles, now you can advance to the final challenge: Unscrambling the 6 letters you will have. After unscrambling, you will have the code (no capitalization however, and no spaces.)

---

Note 1

> Both puzzles can be solved entirely through logical deduction, without the need for guesswork. ***Please do not post answers consisting of only a screenshot of the solved puzzles without a logical explanation to earn the green checkmark. This is so someone can follow along with your steps.***

---

<sub>There's no [gimmick](/questions/tagged/gimmick) tag :(</sub>

Comment: Oof, I just realized that the gimmick in Part 1 can easily be brute-forced. Oops, I'll definitely keep that in mind for later gimmick puzzles.

Comment: I also sadly did not realize until this morning that the first puzzle's gimmick can be easily brute-forced on mobile. I will also keep this in mind for later gimmick puzzles.